# Array Recursion Excercise

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

a) Create an array of random numbers, whose size is a power of 2. Using loops, find the difference for each pair of values (index 0 & 1, 2 & 3, 4 & 5 etc.) and store them in a new array. Then find the difference for each pair of differences and so on until you have only one difference left.
Hint: Think carefully about your loop bounds

b) Now, create a solution that is 'in place', i.e., It does not require the creation of new arrays. Again, this will require careful consideration of loop bounds.

c) Finally, write a solution that makes use of a recursive function, instead of loops.

I have been trying to solve the above exercise but I am stuck with what b means and how can I use recursive function. The following is my solution for part a :

```
public class RandomArray{

    private static double ArrayFn(int p){

        double[] orignalArray = new double[(int)Math.pow(2,p)];
        for (int i = 0; i< orignalArray.length; i++){
            orignalArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10) ;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orignalArray));
        double y = ArrayDifferenceloop(orignalArray);
        System.out.println("Value of Array" + y);
        return y;
    }

    private static double ArrayDifferenceloop(double[] arg){

        do{
            double[] newArr = new double[(arg.length/2)];
            for (int i = 0; i< arg.length; i+=2){
                newArr[i/2] = arg[i] - arg[i+1];
            }
            System.out.println("New Array is =" + Arrays.toString(newArr));
            //copy newArr to arg
            arg = new double[(newArr.length)];
            System.arraycopy(newArr,0,arg,0,newArr.length);
        }while(arg.length > 1);

        return arg[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        double z = ArrayFn(3);
        System.out.println("value" + z);
    }
}
```

Comment: conventionally , method names in Java start in lower case

Comment: if the random function produces int numbers, why the array contains double ones?

Comment: @c0der thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you with point b)
you can store the differences in the original array itself:
difference of [0] and [1] put in [0],
difference of [2] and [3] put in [1], 
and so on.
You can calculate the index to put the result from the indexes of the pair or keep two index variables for the result and for picking the pairs.
you just keep iterate over the original array repeatedly, each time over fewer cells until only two cells left.

the recursive solution should be clear...

Comment: It seems that it should be difference of disjoint pairs, 0-1, 2-3 etc.

Comment: just noticed that. corrected the answer accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess option b means use the original array to store the differences, rather than creating a new array.
This can be achieved by dynamically changing the active range of elements used, ignoring others (see also [Sharon Ben Asher answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965516/3992939) ):

```
private static double ArrayDifferenceloop(double[] array){

    int activeLength = array.length;  
    do{
        int index =0; //index where to store difference
        for (int i = 0; i< activeLength; i+=2){
            array[index++] = array[i] - array[i+1];
        }

        System.out.println("Modified array (only "+index+ " elements are significant) " + Arrays.toString(array));
        activeLength /=2;
    }while(activeLength > 1);

    return array[0];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/* Solution for part (b) hope it works for you*/
public class RandomArray{
 static int len;          /*modification*/
private static double ArrayFn(int p){
double[] orignalArray = new double[(int)Math.pow(2,p)];
len=(int)Math.pow(2,p);
for (int i = 0; i< orignalArray.length; i++){
  orignalArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10) ;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orignalArray));
double y = ArrayDifferenceloop(orignalArray);
System.out.println("Value of Array" + y);
return y;
}


 private static double ArrayDifferenceloop(double[] arg){

do{
  for (int i = 0; i< len; i+=2){         /*modification*/
    arg[i/2] = arg[i] - arg[i+1];
  }
          //copy newArr to arg
  //arg = new double[(arg.length)];
        len=len/2;                 /*modification*/
        System.out.print("new Array : ");
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    System.out.print(arg[i]+" , ");
    }
 // System.arraycopy(arg,0,arg,0,len);
}while(len > 1);

return arg[0];


  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    double z = ArrayFn(3);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orignalArray));
    System.out.println("value" + z);
  }
}
```